# Html5 video local is not working in Android webview

Tags: android, html, video, webview

I am played the html5 video from html5 content in webview android . It works fine.Video is keep playing i moved to the another activity. So the video activity is finished . Then I came to the video activity and play the video, the video is not playing . It show the thumbnail of the video .I click the play icon of the video.But the video is not playing .It again show the thumbnail of the video .I follow the code here Video plays only once in Webview of Android . please help me

Here is my HTML code:

**HTML**

```
<body onload="func()">
    <video id='video' src='video/real.mp4' controls /></video>
    <div class="video_player">
        <img id="image" src="video/vid.jpg" onclick="playVideo()" style="width:100%;height:100%"/>
    </div>
```

**script**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function func(){
            document.getElementById("video").style.display="none";

        }
```

** Function for play video **

```
        function playVideo(){
            var myVideo = document.getElementById("video");
            myVideo.style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("image").style.display="none";

            new MediaElement('video', {
                enablePluginDebug: false,
                plugins: ['flash','silverlight'],
                type: '',
                pluginPath: 'js/johndyer-mediaelement-c4dae2f/',
                flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
                silverlightName: 'silverlightmediaelement.xap',
                defaultVideoWidth: 1280,
                defaultVideoHeight: 720,
                pluginWidth: -1,
                pluginHeight: -1,
                timerRate: 250,
                success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
                    mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
                        var time = mediaElement.currentTime;
                    }, false);
                    mediaElement.play();
                },
                error: function () { 
                }
            });
        }
```

** Action perform after end of video **

```
        var videos = document.getElementById("video");
        videos.addEventListener("ended",closeVideo,true);
        function closeVideo(){
            //videos.style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("image").style.display="block";
            document.location.href = "03_video.html"
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

I just reload the html page that is 03_video.html

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: I have edited and gave the html code.

Comment: anybody please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Use this customized HTML5 WebView. Hope it will solve your problem

```
 public class HTML5WebView extends WebView {

private Context mContext;
private MyWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;
private View mCustomView;
private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;

private FrameLayout mContentView;
private FrameLayout mBrowserFrameLayout;
private FrameLayout mLayout;

static final String TAG = "HTML5WebView";

private void init(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    Activity a = (Activity) mContext;

    mLayout = new FrameLayout(context);

    mBrowserFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(
            R.layout.custom_screen, null);
    mContentView = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.main_content);
    mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);

    mLayout.addView(mBrowserFrameLayout, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);

    mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
    setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

    setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    // Configure the webview
    WebSettings s = getSettings();
    s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    s.setSavePassword(true);
    s.setSaveFormData(true);
    s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // enable navigator.geolocation
    s.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    s.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/com.example.vimeotest/databases/");

    // enable Web Storage: localStorage, sessionStorage
    s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    mContentView.addView(this);
}

public HTML5WebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

public FrameLayout getLayout() {
    return mLayout;
}

public boolean inCustomView() {
    return (mCustomView != null);
}

public void hideCustomView() {
    mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if ((mCustomView == null) && canGoBack()) {
            goBack();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private Bitmap mDefaultVideoPoster;
    private View mVideoProgressView;

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view,
            WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {

        HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }

        mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
        mCustomView = view;
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {

        if (mCustomView == null)
            return;

        // Hide the custom view.
        mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Remove the custom view from its container.
        mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
        mCustomView = null;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

        HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {

        if (mDefaultVideoPoster == null) {
            mDefaultVideoPoster = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), R.drawable.default_video_poster);
        }
        return mDefaultVideoPoster;
    }

    @Override
    public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {

        if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.video_loading_progress, null);
        }
        return mVideoProgressView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {

        ((Activity) mContext).setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

        ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().setFeatureInt(
                Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, newProgress * 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
            GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        // don't override URL so that stuff within iframe can work properly
        // view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }

}

static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

}

PlayerActvity:

```
  public class VimeoVideoActivity extends Activity {
private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private HTML5WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);

    // Auto playing vimeo videos in Android webview
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.OFF);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("URL");
    // mWebView.loadUrl("http://player.vimeo.com/api/examples/simple");
    // F mWebView.loadUrl("http://vimeo.com/watch");
    // mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.4:9090/playground.html");
    // mWebView.loadUrl("http://ua.brad.is");
    setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

    mWebView.stopLoading();
}

}
```

Comment: I can't understand why you are taking PluginState.OFF ?

Comment: f there is no need to support plugins (such as Flash!), then disable support for plugins as these could be used as a vector to exploit your applications process. The Android WebSettings class can be used to disable support for JavaScript via the public deprecated method setPluginsEnabled.
webview = new WebView(this);
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(false);
Or the method setPluginState
webview = new WebView(this);
webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.OFF);

Comment: But this code is not working in my application.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Send me some html5 videos link. Lemme try it and let you know

Comment: Here is my code. Now please give the way so that I can rectify my code.

Comment: video is playing once but in second time it shows blank screen but audio is working